# Bound on the maximum coefficient of polynomial.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Let $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d c_i x^i$ be a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $d$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\max_{x \in [0,1]} p(x) | \leq 1
\end{equation}
Can we derive an upper bound on the maximum coefficient (in absolute value),
that is 
$$
 \max_i |c_i| \leq C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant ?

I can get an upper bound on $c_0$ since
$ |p(0)| = |c_0| \leq 1$, but I cannot get an upper bound for 
the absolute value of the maximum coefficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257909/find-the-maximum-of-a-p-if-a-0a-1x-dotsa-nxn-1-1-mapsto-1-1/257918#257918